# Delete button gives me error

Tags: apex, visualforce, delete

My delete button does not work after putting endless efforts and thought to post here.When i click on Delete button, its just rerendering and not deleting after trying with actionSupport.

It gives me an error of QueryExcpetion

```
public class PagingTasksController1{

public List<Task> Tasks;


public Task del;
public Task taskDel;
public Integer CountTotalRecords{get;set;}
public String QueryString {get;set;}
public Integer OffsetSize = 0;
private Integer QueryLimit =3 ;
public List<Task> lstTasks {get;set;}
public String searchText {get;set;}
public String rowIndex {get;set;}
public Date mydate;
public Integer totalCount {get;set;}
public string sortField = 'Subject';  // default sort column
private string sApplySOQL = '';
 public List<Task> delattendeeList {get;set;}

public List<Task> delAttendees {get; set;}

public PagingTasksController1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

 taskDel= (Task)controller.getRecord();
 Tasks = [Select id,Subject,Status,ActivityDate from Task where OwnerId =: taskDel.Id];
// this.Tasks=Tasks[0];
 totalCount = Tasks.size();

 delattendeeList = new List<Task>();
 delattendees = new List<Task>();
  }


  // the current sort direction. defaults to ascending
   public String sortDir {
    get  { if (sortDir == null) {  sortDir = 'asc'; } return sortDir;  }
    set;
  }

 // the current field to sort by. defaults to role name
  public String getsortField() {
    return sortField;
}

// the current field to sort by.
 public void setsortField(string value) {
    sortField = value;
 }

// toggles the sorting of query from asc<-->desc
public void toggleSort() {
    // simply toggle the direction
    sortDir = sortDir.equals('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';

    integer iIndex = sApplySOQL.indexOf('Order By');
    if (iIndex > -1){
      sApplySOQL = sApplySOQL.substringBefore('Order By');
      sApplySOQL = sApplySOQL + ' Order By ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir +  ' limit ' + QueryLimit + ' offset ' + OffsetSize;
    }
    tasks = Database.query(sApplySOQL );
}

 public PagingTasksController1 (){
    //CountTotalRecords= [select count() from Task];
    //String qStr2= '7/23/2014';

 }

 public List<Task> getTasks(){
    if(tasks == null){
        tasks = new List<Task>();
    }
    return tasks;
}

   public void findTasks(){
    String qStr2 = 'Select count() from Task where Subject like \'%'+searchText+'%\' OR Status like \'%'+searchText+'%\'';
    CountTotalRecords = Database.countQuery(qStr2);
    queryTasks();
 }

public void  queryTasks(){

    String qStr2= searchText;
    Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
    String strnormal = '';
    try{
         mydate = date.parse(qStr2);
    }catch(Exception e)
    { }

    String strDate = '';
    if(mydate != null) {
     // strnormal = String.valueOf(mydate );
      String[] qstr3 = String.valueOf(mydate).split(' ',2); 
      strDate = ' ActivityDate =  '+ qstr3[0] + ' ';
    }else{

       strDate  =  'Subject like \'%'+searchText +'%\' OR Status like \'%' +searchText+ '%\' Order By '  + sortField;
    }

    if (ownerIds != null && ownerIds.size() > 0){

      String qStr = 'Select OwnerId,Subject,Status,ActivityDate from Task where '+strDate+' limit ' + QueryLimit + ' offset ' + OffsetSize +' and OwnerId in :ownerIds';
      System.debug(qStr); 
      tasks = Database.query(qStr);         
    }

       //String qStr ='Select OwnerId,Subject,Status,ActivityDate from Task where \''+strDate +'\' limit ' + QueryLimit + ' offset ' + OffsetSize;
      // String qStr = 'Select OwnerId,Subject,Status,ActivityDate from Task where '+strDate+' limit ' + QueryLimit + ' offset ' + OffsetSize;


        //  String qStr = 'Select OwnerId,Subject,Status,Priority from Task where Subject like \'%'+searchText+'%\' OR Status like \'%'+searchText+ '%\' Order By ' + sortField;

   //tasks.sort();

     }

   public Boolean getDisablePrevious(){
    if(OffsetSize>0){
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}

 public Boolean getDisableNext() {
    if (OffsetSize + QueryLimit < countTotalRecords){
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}

  public PageReference Next() {
    OffsetSize += QueryLimit;
    queryTasks();
    return null;
}

  public PageReference Previous() {
    OffsetSize -= QueryLimit;
    queryTasks();
    return null;
   }

  public PageReference save() {
    update tasks;
    return ApexPages.CurrentPage();
   }

  public void deleteRow(){

     rowIndex = String.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rowIndex'));
     System.debug('rowIndex ------------'+rowIndex );
     if(rowIndex!=null)
     {
     Task check=[Select id from Task where id=: rowIndex];
     System.debug('row to be deleted ' + check);
     delete check;
     Tasks=[Select Subject,Status,ActivityDate,OwnerId from Task ];
     update Tasks;
       }
     }
   }
```

VF Page:

```
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Tasks}" var="tsk" id="pgTable">

     <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
       <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRow}" reRender="pgTable">
       <apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!tsk.id}"/>
      </apex:commandButton>             
    </apex:column>


         <!-- <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
        <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Task.Delete, .id,['retURL'='/apex/New_Test_task_Assignment'])}"> Delete</apex:outputLink>
       </apex:column>  -->

    <apex:column headerValue="OwnerId">
        <apex:outputField value="{!tsk.OwnerId}"/>
    </apex:column>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the conventional way to get the [apex:param](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_param.htm) value set on the controller:

```
<apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!tsk.id}" assignTo="{!rowIndex}" />
```

and then all that `deleteRow` needs to do is to use the ID value (rowIndex ought to be renamed taskId) for the delete and then remove that item from the list of Tasks (or call `queryTasks` to build the list over again without the deleted Task):

```
public void deleteRow(){
    delete new Task(Id = rowIndex);
    for (Integer i = 0; i < Tasks.size(); i++) {
        if (Tasks[i].Id == rowIndex) {
            Tasks.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```